# Problems with capturing the Screensaver event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to capture a screensaver event, however when I run my application and go to personalise > screensaver >preview and turn the screensaver on, nlog won't write to the log, it's as if the event isn't being picked up!

code is below

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref int ipvParam, int fuWinini);

        const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;
        static int screenSaverRunning = -1;
        int ok = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref screenSaverRunning, 0);

        private void ScreenSaver()
        {
            if (ok == 0)
            {
                Logger.Trace("SCREENSAVER OFF");
            }

            if (screenSaverRunning != 0)
            {
                Logger.Trace("SCREENSAVER ON");

            }
    }
```

Comment: Could point 3 in this answer be of any help http://superuser.com/a/538849/189858? it says the event isn't tracked by default.

Comment: I appreciate the help but that relates to the windows event logger, I'd like to use Nlog preferably, in an ideal world I'd be able to pick up the Screensaver on event, then write to the nlog file when that event fires